# Token w/ liquidty fees - create LP pair before send tokens to pancakeswap or to burn?

Tags: tokens, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

If I create a token (through cointool.app) that has liquidity fees, and I want to burn some of the supply after creating it, and I need to send the rest to pancakeswap for trading - do I need to create the LP pair first before doing these as the transaction of sending tokens to the burn wallet or to the contract address will automatically detract the fees that go to the liquidity?

*

I've tried through testnet but you can't choose liquidity fees on testnet; so what I did was instead put burn fees in place of that.

I then created the token, and immediately burned some of the supply.

It showed that the burned tokens got sent to the burn address, but transaction fees were detracted from this transaction automatically (so the 3% went to the burn address)

--> so basically, if the transaction fee was 'liquidity' and not 'burn' then that 3% would go to the LP... but that means I need to create the LP first, then burn and send to contract address, correct?